# InputStream - mark, skip, read, reset

Tags: java, inputstream, peek

The API documentation of **[`InputStream::mark(int readlimit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark(int))** and **[`InputStream::reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset())** is clear about subsequent `read` calls - the `InputStream` can be reset as long as `mark` is supported and no more then `readlimit` bytes have been read.

My question is - is this also true for subsequent `skip` calls? In other words - can I `skip` and `read` less then `readlimit` bytes combined and then `reset` the stream? Or does `skip` not count as a "reset-able" operation?

I know I could just test it and find out, or even better - read some sources of existing `InputStream` implementations. But as I'm developing my own `InputStream` - I want to understand from a "general contract" perspective - do you think it should be implemented with or without support for `skip`? (I am asking since it may introduce some code complications in my implementation).

Comment: Sounds like something that can be tried out.

Comment: Thanks @LutzHorn, Please see my edit

Comment: From the contract point of view, if it's not in the JavaDoc, it's not in the contract.

Comment: I don't see any documentation that says `skip` is allowed to invalidate the mark. Is it difficult for you to support reset after skip?

Comment: Look at the implementation of other InputStream subclasses in the standard API. Take BufferedInputStream for example, there the skip method does allow a reset to revert back to before the skipped bytes: "// If no mark position set then don't keep in buffer" and "// Fill in buffer to save bytes for reset". The javadoc for InputStream is ambiguous, but this clearly show the intentation of the API authors to allow bytes skipped by `skip` to be reset back into.

Comment: It is - I am writing a wrapper around a given `InputStream` that might, or might not, support `mark`. I have no assurance as of what the concrete implementation of the underlying stream would be and how it will act when I delegate a call to it's `skip`, so I would have to `read` instead and maintain a buffer by myself even though `markSupported` returns `true` (which I can require in my API and enforce at runtime). In other words - if I can't rely on `any` implementation to act as expected - I cannot delegate `mark` and `reset` calls and will have to implement them myself.